# Is there a way to "logoff" a Rails user authenticated via X509 cert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x509

I can delete the cookie through a logoff action but it doesn't prompt the user to reenter their X509 password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the password for their corresponding private key for their Certificate? If you are, they don't even have to have a password to their private key. They set that up themselves when they generated their public/private keys.

The password they use for their private key has nothing to do with your system, thus you shouldn't have any way of forcing them to re-enter a password.

If you don't like the idea of them being able to log in with only "something they have" then you'll need to implement a system with "something they know" also, such as a password. Right now if you are allowing log ins with Certificates then there really isn't a "log out" mechanism, except to remove the Certificate from the system. This is typically done with CAC's or thumb drives. The certificates stay on a mobile/removable type device and goes with the user.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.  Deleting the cookie at least forces the client to authenticate again so that's better than nothing.